# what's the correct dt/dx in this substitution

Tags: integration

I have
$$\int \frac{\tan^3 x+ \tan x}{\tan^3x + 3\tan^2x +2 \tan x+6} dx $$
Set $\tan x = t$ to solve this. But what will my $dx$ be?

My approach was:

$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{\cos^2x} \Leftrightarrow dt \times \cos^2x = dt$
But then I've got to replace x with t. And I can't.

I was thinking about $x = \arctan t$ which derivate is $\frac{1}{t^2+1}$. This seems to be more correct, however applying it, I end up with $\int \frac{(t^3)(t^2+1)}{t^3+3t^2+2t+6} dt$ and that's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember $1+\tan^2 x=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$. So you can do

$$dx=\cos^2 x\,dt=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

Your final remark is on the right tracks, but somehow your integral is not the same as you started with: extra $6$ underneath, $t^3$ instead of $t^3+t$ and $t^2+1$ on the wrong side of the fraction.

By the way, you can just cancel one $\tan x$ and your numerator already fits the substitution: $(\tan^2 x +1)dx=dt$.

Comment: The 6 should be there, my mistake. However now I've $\int \frac{t}{(t+3)(t^2+2)} dt$ wich is solvable, but I'm having problems with t^2. How to approach that?

Comment: Split into partial fractions, $A/(t+3)+(Bt+C)/(t^2+2)$. You get an integral that's easily resolved to logarithms and arctan functions.